# Куда делся RequiresApi в AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день, не могу импортировать `RequiresApi`.

Ошибка:

```
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi; - (Cannot resolve symbol 'RequiresApi')
```

Используется в проекте Android Image Cropper, часть кода:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public void start(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull android.app.Fragment fragment) {
            fragment.startActivityForResult(getIntent(context), CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Comment: min api какой ?

Comment: @Flippy minSdkVersion 17

Comment: А сам пакет импортируется? Другие суппорт аннотации

Comment: @Flippy да, но отмечены желтым... NonNull и Nullable

Comment: @Flippy , надо было добавить compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0' в проект, все нормально, вопрос закрыт!)